# jQuery CDN on google does not seem to get cached?

Tags: jquery, caching, cdn

[here is the JSBIN](http://output.jsbin.com/lidimawele)

i use

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

screenshot of the result

basically it is not cached, the browser goes and checks if it is modified or not, which is time well wasted, and e.g. will fail if working offline.

[image]

Comment: remove https: and just use src="//ajax.googleapis.com/......."

Comment: have you tried doing that? because I did

Comment: If you are getting a 304, it's definitely cached. Are you certain it is doing this during normal operation, or only when the Inspector is open. Perhaps the 'do not cache' is checked? (though I think you'd get a 200 rather than a 304 there).